# Multiple `vmap` in JAX?

Tags: python, vectorization, jax

This may me a very simple thing, but I was wondering how to perform mapping in the following example.

Suppose we have a function that we want to evaluate derivative with respect to `xt`, `yt` and `zt`, but it also takes additional parameters `xs`, `ys` and `zs`.

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import grad, vmap

def fn(xt, yt, zt, xs, ys, zs):
    return jnp.sqrt((xt - xs) ** 2 + (yt - ys) ** 2 + (zt - zs) ** 2)
```

Now, let us define the input data:

```py
xt = jnp.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
yt = jnp.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
zt = jnp.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
xs = jnp.array([1., 2., 3.])
ys = jnp.array([3., 3., 3.])
zs = jnp.array([1., 1., 1.])
```

In order to evaluate gradient for each pair of data points in `xt`, `yt` and `zt`, I have to do the following:

```py
fn_prime = vmap(grad(fn, argnums=(0, 1, 2)), in_axes=(None, None, None, 0, 0, 0))

a = []
for _xt in xt:
    for _yt in yt:
        for _zt in zt:
            a.append(fn_prime(_xt, _yt, _zt, xs, ys, zs))
```

and it results in a list of tuples.
Once the list is converted to a `jnp.array`, it is of the following shape:

```py
a = jnp.array(a)
print(f`shape = {a.shape}')
```

```py
shape = (64, 3, 3)
```

My question is:
Is there a way to avoid this for loop and evaluate all gradients in the same sweep?

Answer (score 3):

A good rule of thumb for cases like this is that each nested `for` loop translates to a nested `vmap` over an appropriate `in_axis`. With this in mind, you can re-express your computation this way:

```python
def f_loops(xt, yt, zt, xs, ys, zs):
  a = []
  for _xt in xt:
    for _yt in yt:
      for _zt in zt:
        a.append(fn_prime(_xt, _yt, _zt, xs, ys, zs))
  return jnp.array(a)

def f_vmap(xt, yt, zt, xs, ys, zs):
  f_z = vmap(fn_prime, in_axes=(None, None, 0, None, None, None))
  f_yz = vmap(f_z, in_axes=(None, 0, None, None, None, None))
  f_xyz = vmap(f_yz, in_axes=(0, None, None, None, None, None))
  return jnp.stack(f_xyz(xt, yt, zt, xs, ys, zs), axis=3).reshape(64, 3, 3)

out_loops = f_loops(xt, yt, zt, xs, ys, zs)
out_vmap = f_vmap(xt, yt, zt, xs, ys, zs)

np.testing.assert_allclose(out_loops, out_vmap)  # passes
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jakevdp. 
Is (on average) nesting `jax.vmap` computationally cheaper than nesting `jax.lax.scan`?

Answer (score 0):

You could vectorize the gradient and give a grid-like input for the diff arguments:

```
def f_vect(xt, yt, zt, xs, ys, zs):
    fp = jnp.vectorize(grad(fn, argnums=(0, 1, 2)))
    fn_prime = vmap(fp, in_axes=(None, None, None, 0, 0, 0))
    
    a = jnp.array(fn_prime(xt[:, None, None], 
                           yt[None, :, None], 
                           zt[None, None, :],
                           xs, ys, zs)) # has shape 3,3,4,4,4
    
    a = a.reshape(a.shape[0], a.shape[1], -1) # has shape 3,3,64
    a = jnp.rollaxis(a, -1) # has shape 64,3,3
    
    return a
```